# what is url robot search engine when enter to my website

Tags: seo, htaccess, robots.txt

what is url search engine robots when enter to my website

for example i add this code in `.htaccess`

this code just allow google robots read the `robots.txt`

i need to add url ( msn , yahoo , bing ) robots to this code

```
<Files robots.txt>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from googlebot.com google.com google-analytics.com
</Files>
```

Comment: Why do you want to block other bots/users from even reading your `robots.txt` file? `Allow from googlebot.com ...` - that directive is not doing what you think it is doing and is most likely _blocking_ Googlebot, not allowing it. What Apache version are you on?

Answer (score 1):

You should achieve this through robots.txt not .htaccess.
If you want to allow all spiders (search engine crawlers) to visit and index your website, you need following robots.txt rules.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```